# Richfaces portlet | FacesContext not found

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, portlet, websphere-portal

I am tying to create a portlet using RichFaces 3.3. I created a portlet project in IBM RSA. The sample portlet generated by IBM RSA works fine but as soon as I add JSF/RichFaces components to the `.jsp` page I receive `Error 500: java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found` exception.

I am performing following steps to create this portlet in IBM RSA 8:

- New->Portlet Project, A new project with following settings:
  Configuration: JSR286 Basic, Web 2.0 Features: Client-side
  capabilities
- copy all the libraries needed for richface to WEB_INF/lib
- export portlet project as .war
- Deploy and run .war file using IBM Websphere Portal Administration
  module.

The resulting portlet is deployed on IBM websphere portal Server successfully but the portlet displays nothing but an exception message `Error 500: java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found`.

Can anybody point out what am I doing wrong here ? Any help, hints, pointers are appreciated.

Following stack trace (including logging when portlet is installed and run on the server) is displayed on the server console:

```
[6/7/12 15:13:11:729 PKT] 00000067 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module loginBasic has been bound to default_host[*:80,*:443,*:10000,*:10002,*:10039,*:10029,*:10032].
[6/7/12 15:13:11:746 PKT] 00000067 ApplicationMg A WSVR0221I: Application started: PA_loginBasic
[6/7/12 15:13:11:751 PKT] 00000067 CompositionUn A WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=PA_loginBasic in BLA WebSphere:blaname=PA_loginBasic started.
[6/7/12 15:13:40:632 PKT] 00000045 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [PA_loginBasic] [/wps/PA_loginBasic] [loginBasic]: Initialization successful.
[6/7/12 15:13:40:648 PKT] 00000045 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [PA_loginBasic] [/wps/PA_loginBasic] [/_loginBasic/jsp/html/LoginBasicPortletView.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[6/7/12 15:13:40:932 PKT] 00000045 servlet       E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: Uncaught exception created in one of the service methods of the servlet /_loginBasic/jsp/html/LoginBasicPortletView.jsp in application PA_loginBasic. Exception created : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: FacesContext not found
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.getFacesContext(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:321)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.setJspId(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:228)
    at com.ibm._jsp._LoginBasicPortletView._jspx_meth_f_view_0(_LoginBasicPortletView.java:428)
    at com.ibm._jsp._LoginBasicPortletView._jspService(_LoginBasicPortletView.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:353)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.core.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.core.impl.PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.include(PortletRequestDispatcherImpl.java:237)
    at com.ibm.loginbasic.LoginBasicPortlet.doView(LoginBasicPortlet.java:43)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.doDispatch(GenericPortlet.java:328)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:222)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:128)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.el.init.AttributeCopyFilter.doFilter(AttributeCopyFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPortletFilter.doFilter(IWidgetPortletFilter.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.propertybroker.standard.filter.C2APortletFilter.doFilter(C2APortletFilter.java:193)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.plm.GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.java:141)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:573)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doRender(PortletServletCollaborator.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doRender(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:155)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.webextension.PortletExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(PortletExtensionProcessor.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPCInvokerCollaborator.doRender(IWidgetPCInvokerCollaborator.java:173)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:251)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$1.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:98)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:182)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:148)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:128)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.doRenderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:641)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.ext.render.AbstractRenderManager.performService(AbstractRenderManager.java:263)
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:132)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutControlDataSource.renderPortlet(LayoutControlDataSource.java:820)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutControlDataSource.renderLayoutControl(LayoutControlDataSource.java:764)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutControlDataSource.write(LayoutControlDataSource.java:1132)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wps.util.ContextWrapper$Handler.invoke(ContextWrapper.java:127)
    at $Proxy161.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.skin.DynamicContentSkinContentHandler.endDynamicContentSpot(DynamicContentSkinContentHandler.java:251)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.skin.RecordingSkinContentHandler.parse(RecordingSkinContentHandler.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.skin.CachingSkinURIParserImpl.parse(CachingSkinURIParserImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.parse(LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.java:278)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSource.write(LocalizedContextDataSource.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.skin.DynamicContentSkinDataSource.write(DynamicContentSkinDataSource.java:188)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.skins.SPASkinTemplate.render(SPASkinTemplate.java:235)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.SkinTemplate.render(SkinTemplate.java:68)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:736)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Control.render(Control.java:182)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Component.render(Component.java:652)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.elements.Control.render(Control.java:165)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:3103)
    at com.ibm.wps.composition.Composition.render(Composition.java:164)
    at com.ibm.websphere.personalization.transformation.PznTransformationLayoutModel.render(PznTransformationLayoutModel.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.model.wrappers.LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl$LayoutModelWrapperImpl.render(LayoutModelWrapperFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.DefaultPageRendererImpl.renderLayoutControlWithSkin(DefaultPageRendererImpl.java:1086)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.DefaultPageRendererImpl.renderLayoutControl(DefaultPageRendererImpl.java:1036)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.DefaultPageRendererImpl.renderLayoutContainer(DefaultPageRendererImpl.java:935)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.StaticPageRendererImpl.startPortletContainer(StaticPageRendererImpl.java:966)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl$PlaybackHandler.playStartPortletContainer(CacheValueImpl.java:581)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl$PlaybackHandler.parse(CacheValueImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl$PlaybackHandler.parse(CacheValueImpl.java:364)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CacheValueImpl.parse(CacheValueImpl.java:1148)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.cache.CachingParser.parse(CachingParser.java:531)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.StaticPageURIParserImpl.parse(StaticPageURIParserImpl.java:137)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.StaticPageURIParserImpl.parse(StaticPageURIParserImpl.java:171)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.render(PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.java:249)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.render(PortalStaticPageRendererImpl.java:192)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.SPAScreenTemplate.render(SPAScreenTemplate.java:152)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.SPAScreenTemplate.render(SPAScreenTemplate.java:119)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.screens.SPAScreenTemplate.render(SPAScreenTemplate.java:170)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ScreenTemplate.render(ScreenTemplate.java:59)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.model.layout.LayoutTemplateDataSource.write(LayoutTemplateDataSource.java:294)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wps.util.ContextWrapper$Handler.invoke(ContextWrapper.java:127)
    at $Proxy155.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor81.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at com.ibm.wps.util.ContextWrapper$Handler.invoke(ContextWrapper.java:127)
    at $Proxy156.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.renderer.theme.DynamicContentThemeContentHandler.endDynamicContentSpot(DynamicContentThemeContentHandler.java:249)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.theme.RecordingThemeContentHandler.parse(RecordingThemeContentHandler.java:109)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.parser.theme.CachingThemeURIParserImpl.parse(CachingThemeURIParserImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.parse(LocalizedContextDataSourceParserImpl.java:278)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.locale.LocalizedContextDataSource.write(LocalizedContextDataSource.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wps.spa.data.theme.DynamicContentThemeDataSource.write(DynamicContentThemeDataSource.java:186)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.tags.DataSourceTag.doEndTag(DataSourceTag.java:229)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_r_dataSource_0(_Default.java:2944)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspx_meth_c_when_2(_Default.java:2971)
    at com.ibm._jsp._Default._jspService(_Default.java:943)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:686)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.handleRequest(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.DispatcherServiceImpl.include(DispatcherServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.dispatcher.Dispatcher.include(Dispatcher.java:50)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.doDispatch(Default.java:294)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.themes.Default.render(Default.java:247)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.templates.ThemeTemplate.render(ThemeTemplate.java:65)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPRenderPhase.processRendering(WPRenderPhase.java:509)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:230)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:100)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:955)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:677)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1429)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:672)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1417)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter$ExtendedFilterChain.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:412)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
```

Environment: WebSphere Portal v7.0, IBM Rational® Software Architect Version: 8.0.4, JSR 286, JSF 1.2, Richfaces 3.3.

Comment: Why is it closed?. I am facing a specific issue and I have asked for help. I understand that the stack trace make it extra large but then its just stack trace. An the down voter should care to explain. Thanks

Comment: In the future please don't quote the stacktrace, but just put in code block. As to your concrete problem, the request URL was just wrong. It has to match `FacesServlet` mapping. See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.RuntimeException%3A+FacesContext+not+found

Comment: @casperOne: 1st of all I haven't posted any large block of code or asked for any reviews etc. I just posted stacktrace of exception I am getting. Is it a bad practice ?